# What is .clone() doing with arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, clone

For example

```
int[] test = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

and I want to clone it (deep copy)

```
int[] another = test.clone();
```

What is Java really doing here? Is it copying all the elements individually (*O(n)*) or something else?

Comment: How is this supposed to not be *O(n)* in your opinion?

Comment: Refer to the documentation of Object#clone. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--

Comment: Or you can check out the source code.

Comment: Intuitively it feels like O(n) but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @user809495 Well, if you clone an array, you have to read each element at least once. You cannot skip the reading of some elements with some clever algorithm. If you want to clone an element, you have to read it, doesn't matter how. This is inherently *O(n)*.

Comment: Please note that `clone()` is in fact performing a shallow clone and not a deep clone as written in your question.

Comment: You're right. I should have done more research before saying that.

Comment: So is doing int[] another = test.clone() the same as doing int[] another = test?

Comment: @user809495 Please, don't do edits on your question post that essentially change the question itself. The "deep copy"-thing was a part of your question. It's okay to keep it there even when you got comments with clarification about it. It's absolutely fine to not be aware of everything when asking. That's what asking questions is for.

Comment: @user809495 No, `int[] another = test.clone()` is not the same as `int[] another = test`. The one clones the values of `test`, the other just assigns `test` to `another`. See my answer below for a bit more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

When you clone an array, you need to read each element at least once. You cannot skip the reading of some elements with some clever algorithm. If you want to clone an element, you have to read it. This is inherently *O(n)*.

The [`Object#clone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) method

> [...] creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

In other words, this method copies *values*. When you have an `int[]`, the *values* are copied and *assigned* to the new array. When you have an `Object[]`, still, the *values* are copied and *assigned*. Keep in mind that a reference is just a value as well.

The content of an `int[]` are the integer values. Thus, you can change a cloned array without affecting the original array. The content of an `Object[]` are *references*. A cloned *reference* will still point at the *same* object. Thus, if you access an object in the cloned array, you *will* access the *same* object that is referenced in the original array as well.

Comment: So what you're saying is that a cloned object is a new object but all its values are references to to original object . Did I get that right?

Comment: @user809495 I think my answer and the documentation are written very clearly. If you are unsure about something, you should take your time *understanding* what I've written there and what is written in the documentation.